# c program fork and wait golang process status

Tags: go, wait, exit

C program:

```
pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
    execv("Golang Process");
} else (pid > 0) {
    wait(&status);
    printf("process %d status: %d\n", pid);
}
```

Golang Program:

```
func main() {
    ......
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

But, output is:
process XXX status: 256

if set os.Exit(2), output is:
process XXX status: 512

if set os.Exit(3), output is:
process XXX status: 768

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`wait` manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait):

> If status is not NULL, `wait()` and `waitpid()` store **status information**
>   in the int to which it points. **This integer can be inspected with the
>   following macros (which take the integer itself as an argument, not a
>   pointer to it, as is done in `wait()` and `waitpid()`!)**:
>
> `WIFEXITED(status)` returns `true` if the child terminated normally, that
>   is, by calling `exit(3)` or `_exit(2)`, or by returning from `main()`.
>
> `WEXITSTATUS(status)` returns the exit status of the child. This
>   consists of the least significant 8 bits of the status argument that
>   the child specified in a call to `exit(3)` or `_exit(2)` or as the
>   argument for a return statement in `main()`. This macro should only be
>   employed if `WIFEXITED` returned `true`.

Your issue is unrelated to golang, you just have to use these macros to extract the status code:

```
if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
  printf("process %d status: %d\n", pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
```